# AMQPLib Detecting / Handling Channel Close

Tags: node.js, node-amqp

I'm looking for the recommended way to deal with un-expected channel closures via this library.

I gather from the documentation that there is an event emitted, but it's not quite clear to me how best to detect that event (I know this is simple, but I'm not very clear on event emitting in general, so bear with me), moreover, it's not obvious what I should do with that.

Should I be tracking which subscribers use that channel and then re-subscribe them?  What do others do?

What's more - is there no way to examine the Channel (or ConfirmedChannel) object, and determine if it's still "good"?  This would almost seem preferable to the event-trapping approach, but I can't seem to find a way to do it (ok, that's not exactly true - I've done some things with examining the "accept" method on the Channel to determine if it's gone bad, but this seems hackish).

Any guidance is appreciated.